# Header Tag <title>How can I change Product wise dynamically?

Tags: magento2, php, header, tags, title

I want to Change my header title tag product wise dynamically.my Magento version is 2.3.4. how can I get SKU title to set header title tag? I want to solve this problem. I want to Dynamically change title

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module.

**app/code/Cavendish/ProductPageTitle/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Cavendish_ProductPageTitle',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Cavendish/ProductPageTitle/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cavendish_ProductPageTitle" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**app/code/Cavendish/ProductPageTitle/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="layout_generate_blocks_before">
      <observer name="product_page_title_change" instance="Cavendish\ProductPageTitle\Observer\ChangeProductPageTitle"/>
   </event>
</config>
```

**app/code/Cavendish/ProductPageTitle/Observer/ChangeProductPageTitle.php**

```
<?php

namespace Cavendish\ProductPageTitle\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class ChangeProductPageTitle implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry   
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry; 
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $full_action_name = $observer->getFullActionName();

        if($full_action_name != 'catalog_product_view'){
            return $this;
        }
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');
        if($product){
            $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            $sku = $product->getSku();
            $product->setMetaTitle($title." - ".$sku);// $product->setMetaTitle('Your Title For Product Page');
        }
       return $this;   
    }
}
```

Comment: There is some issue :-

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ChangeProductPageTitle does not exist

Comment: It's mean not clear @klaus :( what does mean 230 character in body??

Comment: Share your files and code here.

Comment: Checkout This link :- https://imgur.com/a/GwCzpRa
last image dicomple error

Comment: You need to replace "[Vendor]" and "[Module]" words with your chosen name. Anyways check out the updated answer.

Comment: Bro actually It's not work.
after that i was do the complile command in magento project then my website show the white space.then i was do the setup upgrade command and cash clear flush command .it's not work for me bro